# Postgresql slow count with like

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I've got a simple flat table with approx. 18 million rows.
Now I need to count a field with the ILIKE operator.
This query returns approx half a million rows. When the search item is "narrower" (a longer search string) everything is fast.

```
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM "KbaData" AS k
WHERE k."KbaKey" ILIKE '1313%'
```

but this runs for 30s, a way too long.
The index on this field is defined as:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IX_KbaData_KbaKey"
    ON public."KbaData" USING gin
    ("KbaKey" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The analyze returns this:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=3370561.68..3370561.69 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=35821.869..35832.270 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=3370561.46..3370561.67 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=35821.690..35832.235 rows=3 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=3369561.46..3369561.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=35787.156..35787.158 rows=1 loops=3)"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ""KbaData"" k  (cost=0.00..3364441.38 rows=2048033 width=0) (actual time=104.308..35644.469 rows=1498715 loops=3)"
"                    Filter: (""KbaKey"" ~~* '1313%'::text)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 3271997"
"Planning Time: 0.231 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 14"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 1.512 ms, Inlining 200.964 ms, Optimization 62.820 ms, Emission 48.232 ms, Total 313.528 ms"
"Execution Time: 35832.920 ms"
```

How can I do it better?

Comment: WHat is the execution plan when you `SET enable_seqscan = off;`?

Comment: What Data Type is KbaKey?  That implicit "::text" conversion before filtering it looks highly suspicious to me.  It's also forcing the query to Table Scan, which will be slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the search item is "narrower" (a longer search string) everything is fast

Counting 1/3 of the table is very likely be slower than counting, say, 1/100000 of the table.

For this case with only a following wildcard in the pattern, using a btree index with text_pattern_ops operator would probably be faster, as it can use an index-only scan.  (But it will still be counting 1/3 of the table, so don't have too high of hopes)

Bitmap scans can use index-only scans for count queries, except that the LIKE operator with trigrams always needs to be rechecked, so that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks, a BTREE index additionally speed it up.